# Table bottom border is randomly getting displayed in Outlook desktop app

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table, outlook, html-email

[image]

In above image the table bottom border is missing. It appears randomly when scrolling or when open close the outlook app. This issue occurs only in outlook desktop app but it works fine in browser. Im working in react project, in that we are creating a table with data's and sending it to mail. While viewing in outlook this issue occurs. It works fine in yahoo, gmail domains.

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your source HTML markup?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to your web browser rendering engine displaying the HTML in your email where the outlook desktop app will use it's own rendering engine (basically a slightly modified version of the old Internet Explorer one).

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to see where the problem lies but you would probably need to use some HTML logic to differentiate between whether you're using a browser or Microsoft office.

In your HTML code you can use logic to display different code depending on if you're viewing it in a web broswer or desktop app.

e.g.

```
   <!--[if  mso]>
     <style="some outlook desktop specific styling"> 
   <![endif]-->
   
   <!--[if !mso]>
     <style="some web browser specific styling">
   <!--<![endif]-->
```

If you could post some of your code, I could better explain where you need to make changes.